# change date format to query database

Tags: java, hibernate

how do I change date format of the following date

```
Thu May 17 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012
```

to

```
2012-05-17 00:00:00
```

I need it as date and not as string. I am using

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("")
```

But its not giving the result. 
Actually I am storing the values date wise. So when someone enters the data for the same date again it should overwrite.
If I pass it as date object into the hibernate query it gives the result. But not always. ON few occasions it inserts again that is it inserts duplicate data for the same date. Befroe entering I am adding a method to check if data exists for that date. `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("date", date));`

Comment: you should use `.format()` instead of `.parse()`

Comment: @SamirMangroliya But both are in date format. and .format() does not take date argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing string manipulation at all here. You've said in comments that it's a date/time field in the database, so why would there be *any* string conversion involved in your code?

Specify parameters in JDBC as `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp` or whatever - and then fetch them that way too. Don't do a string conversion. Ignore whatever format happens to be displayed when you query the database in a tool - don't think of the result as having a "format" at all - they're just dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str ="Thu May 17 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012";

        DateFormat old_format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date newDate = null;
        try {
            newDate = old_format.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DateFormat new_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String date = new_format.format(newDate);

        System.out.println("==>"+date);
```

Comment: I want the output as date and not as string.

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly as you do now but change `parse("")` to `format(theDate)`

`theDate` being the Date object you want to format

See
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)

Comment: But .format() returns a string and not date object. I need it in date object.

Comment: The date object does not have a format. When you parse it in the beginning of your code you have it. It represents a specific time. You can choose what to do with it, including formatting it to different formats. What is wrong with the date object? What can you not do?

Comment: when i pass it in a database query, it creates problem. Because in database the format of storage is 2012-05-12 00:00:00. I am checking for already existing values with the date object. But it always returns false although there are objects in the database with that date

Comment: Then perhaps you can format it to the same format the database has and use the string in the where-clause

Comment: There is no where clause. Its a hibernate criteria.

Comment: Then I suggest tagging this question with hibernate and possibly adding it to the title. I think this is more of a question about how to use the hibernate framework.

Comment: @Partha: Why is the field not a date/time-related field in the database? It shouldn't be stored as a string there.

Comment: @JonSkeet Its  date/time field that is why I need as a date and not as string

Comment: @Partha: But if it's a date/time field, you shouldn't need to be doing parsing or formatting in your Java code at all. Pass in values and retrieve them *as date/time values* instead of as strings. You talk about "the format of storage" - you shouldn't care.

Comment: @JonSkeet but in database the HH:mm:ss is always 00:00:00, while querying again with user entered date, this may differ. thats why I need to reformat into 00:00:00 for the later part.

Comment: @Partha: You really don't. You're *still* talking about text formats, when you should be thinking of the date/time values. It sounds like you just need to truncate the date/time value to a date value before sending it in the query.

Comment: @JonSkeet No i want to truncate it but not to date vale but date time itself with time 00:00:00

Comment: @Partha: So you can truncate it to "midnight on that date" - although I'd argue that you're doing the wrong thing at that point. You still don't need to use a *text format*, you just need to provide a different date/time value.

Comment: @JonSkeet "Tue May 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012" this is the object I am passing. And in database 2012-05-22 00:00:00. This does not give proper result always. I mean when querying with Tue May 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012 date object.

Comment: If you fetch a date value from the database, what does it look like? It's entirely possible that you need midnight UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
String date = "Thu May 17 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012";
String oldFormat = "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy";
String newFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(newFormat);
sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(date))
```